# How to interpolate percent coverage?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, interpolation

I have sediment data based on annotated images of the seafloor.  The images are classified into fine sediment, mixed sediment, boulder and outcrop the sum of which is 100% for each image.  For example one image might be 20% mixed and 80% boulder, another 100% outcrop, another 90% fine, 10% boulder.  I would like to interpolate the entire study site based on this point data.

**Is it possible to interpolate based on all 4 fields at the same time or can I only interpolate 1 field at a time?**

I am using arcGIS 10.3.

Comment: One at a time and fix each by 100*individual/total.

Comment: You can interpolate each variable, resulting in 4 raster datasets then composite the raster datasets to create a single 4-band raster dataset.

Comment: Or just create Thiessen polygons from the point data.  The attributes from the points will carry over into the resulting polygons.